# PublishSubject to fire onNext when subscribed

Tags: java, rx-java

I'm trying to create a proxy to my models using RxJava, this proxy lets other subscribe for changes in the model.

Here's a simplified version of my proxy:

```
class MyModelProxy {
    private static MyModelProxy instance;

    private MyModel model;
    private PublishSubject<MyModel> subject;

    private MyModelProxy() {
        this.model = // load from cache
        this.subject = PublishSubject.create();
    }

    public static Observable<MyModel> observe() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new MyModelProxy();
        }

        return instance.subject;
    }

    private void modelUpdated() {
        this.subject.onNext(this.model);
    }
}
```

There's only one instance of `MyModel` in the system, but it might change over time, and so I want to be able to register for these updates.
This code works well if I register on the `Observable` returned from the `observe` method before calling the `onNext` of the subject.

The behavior I want is that when the `subscribe` method is called on this observer then the current instance of `MyModel` will be sent to the subscriber that just subscribed.

I thought about extending the `PublishSubject` but it's final, so I thought about writing my own version of it (mostly by copying what's in `PublishSubject` and adding what I need) but then I found out that `SubjectSubscriptionManager` has package visibility so that's a dead end too.

Any ideas how I can add this needed functionality?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also `BehaviorSubject`, which does exactly what you want: emits most recent and all future items to its subscribers

Comment: Right. Thanks for that!